# NSButton with image - how to get image subview?

Tags: image, cocoa, subview, nsbutton

I can't find, how to get image subview from `NSButton`. I need it to get actual image scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no subview, it is painted by button cell. Use e.g. `-[NSCell imageRectForBounds:]` to get information about its position.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the button subview and you will see NSImageView & NSTextfield. 
Something like this pseudo code:

```
foreach (NSView view in Subviews)
                if (view.GetType() == typeof(NSImageView))
                    imageView = (NSImageView)view;
                else if (view.GetType() == typeof(NSTextField))
                    textField = (NSTextField)view;
```